# Generating XML with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am beginning to use XML in my TSQL queries.

What would the SQL be to generate the following.

```
<SampleXML>
     <Colors>
           <Color name="White"/>
           <Color name="Blue"/>
     </Colors>
     <Fruits>
           <Fruit name="Apple"/>
           <Fruit name="Pineapple"/>
     </Fruits>
</SampleXML>
```

Comment: Generate it from what? The source of the data will influence the TSQL used to produce the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're probably looking for "FOR XML" T-SQL clause

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx

> A SELECT query returns results as a rowset. You can optionally retrieve formal results of a SQL query as XML by specifying the FOR XML clause in the query. The FOR XML clause can be used in top-level queries and in sub queries. The top-level FOR XML clause can be used only in the SELECT statement. In sub queries, FOR XML can be used in the INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements. It can also be used in assignment statements.

take a look on this site too

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh_singh/archive/2010/05/11/export-sql-table-records-to-xml-form.aspx